what is the difference between List subscription component for site and List subscription component endpoints in Maxio Chargify Rest api doc
I was going through the API doc of Maxio Chargify and noticed two endpoints in the API doc under Subscriptions List Subscription components for site and List Subscription Component, by sample response they seem to be giving same response for get call. But is it really the same?
I am trying to build a integration which reaches out to the source, receives data from it, and writes it to a desired destination.
I tried it with the List Subscription Component but I am noticing long sync issues since it is iterating over each subscription_id, so I was thinking of trying the other one, will a customer miss out any data because of this?
